# CakePHP 2: custom HTTP error message in exceptions

Tags: exception, cakephp-2.0

is there a way to customize the HTTP error message in cakePHP exceptions (not in the view but the one shown in Firebug and in ajax response)?

**Example**: if I call an URL with jQuery ajax function i get this error:

```
"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://test.localhost/test/add"
```

because in controller i have

```
if($duplicated){
throw new BadRequestException("Duplicated element!");
}
```

I want to change "Bad Request" to "Duplicated element!" and have something like:

```
"NetworkError: 400 Duplicated element - http://test.localhost/test/add"
```

and (if possible) return an empty layout if the request is ajax.
My code changes only the text in the standard error view.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[CakeResponse::httpCodes($code)](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/cake-response#method-CakeResponsehttpCodes) might help you. But I don't think you can override any existing error codes.

You might consider then [creating your own exception](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html#creating-your-own-application-exceptions).

Comment: Exceptions are the way to go in CakePHP 2.  I wouldn't bother touching the CakeResponse::httpCodes method for something like this.